# PHP Xdebug Netbeans Breakpoints

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, xdebug, breakpoints

After working fine, with no config changes for months xdebug/netbeans is now useless.
I can create breakpoints but whenever it has 'stepped in' to a further scope its impossible to step thru and simply jumps out of the inner scope to the caller.
There are no exceptions generated.

Using tail -f xdebug.log shows breakbpoints being correctly created / removed, Netbeans failed to remove from Ubuntu Software Centre, however I reinstalled over the top of existing. This does not seem clean as Netbeans remembered settings.

### Latest steps:

Ran instructions at https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and rebooted webserver
Of note here it recommended install of xdebug-2.4.1 instead of previously 2.4.0 however this made no difference to current state of NetB / Xdebug combo. I checked php-fpm ini and this correct phpized version still ?

Ran uninstall.sh at /usr/local/netbeans8.*

Downloaded re-install at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html (I also need Java JDK so this is ideal)
Made it executable and ran installer (as sudo)

```
chmod +x jdk-8u101-nb-8_1-linux-x64.sh;
./jdk-8u101-nb-8_1-linux-x64.sh;
```

And nothing changes - this is very frustrating that software designers still cannot be a***d to create proper uninstallers. Still same settings prior to re-install.

### Further

Closed NetBeans again

```
cdl /home
```

then check in each user dir

```
rm -r .netbeans
rm -r NetBeansProjects
```

There was also a directory called nbproject near the site root directory and in the sitefiles repo which is gitted - these was removed.

### Update

Now set up the project including the crap Netbeans debug 'stop at first line' and allowing watches (whats the point of these defaults in a generally used framework norm such as laravel and what is debugging without being able to look at variable values).
Its now begun allowing stepping thru code but after closing debug session will now not allow access to run config. Had to close all projects and reopen.
This proves that its a Netbeans issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem went - maybe on IDE update ?

Answer (score -1):

Created (with a struggle as continually no drop down options) I managed to add a few more debug urls. Its still not possible to do this directly as before so presume Netbeans has done some sort of 'breakit update'.

Testing the URLs in debug mode shows them all to step thru PHP properly now.
To change the URL is now an un-intuitive chore of selecting the project first in the projects tab and hoping to catch it in the drop down.

Therefore since re-install of xdebug showed it the project still broken, then complete manual re-install of the botched uninstall by the actual Netbeans app now shows it working it can only be confirmed that Netbeans is at fault. Shame - I have used Netbeans for years, but for it to cost me 2 days is a liability. Anyone know if Eclipse has improved speed wise ?